# 401 Client Error: Unauthorized for url: https://api.us.onelogin.com/auth/oauth2/v2/tokenth2/v2/token

Tags: api, authorization, onelogin

I have a script that I have been successfully using - not new. I ran it twice this morning with no issues. Suddenly it stopped working and returned: 401 Client Error: Unauthorized for url: https://api.us.onelogin.com/auth/oauth2/v2/tokenth2/v2/token

- code: the same code worked earlier in the day - no changes have been made
- credentials: my credentials are still functioning when logging in manually

what I have tried:

- prior working version, similar code - both use same auth, worked previously
- reboot - when all else fails reboot - no love there either
- vpn: it has never mattered before, but no it did not help
- OneLogin Security Factors:

  - Original security factor: OneLogin Protect
  - Replaced with New OneLogin security factor - failed (yes i removed the original)
  - Replaced with Google with Google Auth - failed (yes i removed the OneLogin)
  - Replaced the Google with OneLogin - failed (yes I removed the Google Auth)
- waited several hours in case all these changes needed to fully replicate - still not working

What in the world am i missing?

Answer (score 0):

Please check you are using for Token

Correct URL is https://api.us.onelogin.com/auth/oauth2/v2/token

Your URL is https://api.us.onelogin.com/auth/oauth2/v2/tokenth2/v2/token